# Sinon ignores subsequent async call

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, chai, sinon, sinon-chai

I need to verify that all transaction calls are succeeded.
Here's the example:

`module.js`

```js
const functionUnderTest = async (helper) => {
  await helper.transaction(async (transaction) => {
    await helper.doSomething();
    await helper.doSomething2();
    await helper.expectedToBeCalled();
    console.log("done");
  });
};
module.exports = {
  functionUnderTest,
};
```

The problem comes, that for some reason with sinon I cannot verify that the last call was done at all, however the message "done" is always printed.

Here how output looks like

```
$ npm run test

> sinon-test@1.0.0 test
> mocha



  module
    ✔ the former function should be called
done
    1) the latter function should be called
done


  1 passing (7ms)
  1 failing

  1) module
       the latter function should be called:
     AssertionError: expected stub to have been called at least once, but it was never called
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/module.test.js:31:48)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The tests itself are represented below

`helpers/chai.js`

```
const chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
const chaiSinon = require("sinon-chai");

chai.use(chaiSinon);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

module.exports = { expect: chai.expect };
```

`test/module.test.js`

```
const { expect } = require("./helpers/chai");
const sinon = require("sinon");
const { functionUnderTest } = require("../module");

describe("module", function () {
  let sandbox;
  let mockHelper;
  const transaction = {};

  beforeEach(function () {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    mockHelper = {
      transaction: sandbox.stub().callsArgWithAsync(0, transaction),
      doSomething: sandbox.stub().resolves({}),
      doSomething2: sandbox.stub().resolves({}),
      expectedToBeCalled: sandbox.stub().resolves({}),
    };
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it("the former function should be called", async function () {
    await functionUnderTest(mockHelper);
    expect(mockHelper.doSomething).to.be.called;
  });

  it("the latter function should be called", async function () {
    await functionUnderTest(mockHelper);
    expect(mockHelper.expectedToBeCalled).to.be.called;
  });
});
```

To make it complete and easy to test, I've created a repo that you can play with: https://github.com/vichugunov/sinon-test

My question are:

- how is it possible?
- what am I doing wrong?

P.S. If the call `await helper.doSomething2()` is commented out, tests are passing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstand async versions `callsArg*` and `yields*` for stubs. See this [PR](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/pull/146/files#diff-048929202de611a3a327c6dff825f9b7a6f04cdbbb4822d8e12415f2126492b1R125), the difference is async versions `callsArg*` will:

> - In Node environment the callback is deferred with `process.nextTick`.
> - In a browser the callback is deferred with `setTimeout(callback, 0)`.

It does **not** wait for the asynchronous callback function to complete. `async/await` in the test case can only wait for the completion of the `await helper.transaction()` asynchronous function, not its asynchronous callback.

The sync version of `callsArg*` will call the callback immediately. You can take a look at this [issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/133), when should use async versions `callsArg*`.

Therefore, when the test case performs an assertion, the asynchronous function such as `helper.expectedTobecalled()` is not completed.

You should use `callsFake()` to provide an async stub callback for `helper.transaction()` method and invoke it with `async/await`.

E.g.

`module.js`:

```js
const functionUnderTest = async (helper) => {
  await helper.transaction(async (transaction) => {
    await helper.doSomething();
    await helper.doSomething2();
    await helper.expectedToBeCalled();
    console.log('done');
  });
};
module.exports = { functionUnderTest };
```

`module.test.js`:

```js
const sinon = require('sinon');
const { functionUnderTest } = require('./module');

describe('module', function () {
  let sandbox;
  let mockHelper;
  const transaction = {};

  beforeEach(function () {
    sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();
    mockHelper = {
      transaction: sandbox.stub().callsFake(async (callback) => {
        await callback(transaction);
      }),
      doSomething: sandbox.stub().resolves({}),
      doSomething2: sandbox.stub().resolves({}),
      expectedToBeCalled: sandbox.stub().resolves({}),
    };
  });

  afterEach(function () {
    sandbox.restore();
  });

  it('the former function should be called', async function () {
    await functionUnderTest(mockHelper);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mockHelper.doSomething);
  });

  it('the latter function should be called', async function () {
    await functionUnderTest(mockHelper);
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(mockHelper.expectedToBeCalled);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
  module
done
    ✓ the former function should be called
done
    ✓ the latter function should be called


  2 passing (5ms)
```